# Update an input field from a dropwdown menu populated by a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I have a graphing calculator I am working on. I want to user to save any valid equation they write. They can choose from the saved equation by selecting a drop down menu. The problem I have is that when I click on any equation in the dropdown menu, the input box is not updated. Is there a way I can update the input box by clicking on any equations?
This is what I have:

```
<!-- Input Box: -->
<label for="inputField">Enter values here. <br> <em>F(x)= (x+t)</em>
                    <input   id="inputField" value="sin(t+x)*tan(x-10)" autocomplete="off" size="20" class=" form-control prompt"> 
                 </label>

    <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
<label id="recevoirDonnee" for="DBpick"> Choose from Database 
                 <select  name="DBpick" id="DBpick" class="selectpicker" >
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($expressions)) {
                       echo "<option value=$row[1]>$row[1]</option>";
                    }
            </select>
   <script>


$('select').on('change', function() {
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
$('#inputField').val($(this).val()));
});
   </script>
```

My problem is that when I select anything on the dropdown, It doesn't update the input field. What is wrong with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('select[name="DBpick"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#inputField').val($(this).val())
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ys3VN/)

You didn't need the `.each()` function as there is only one selected value at one time.

**FOR UPDATING URLS's**

You can change the entire URL and TITLE by using HTML5's new `pushState` feature. Be warned using this though, as older browsers do not support this feature. For example, IE first supported it in version 10. Here's a [list of supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history). To use this, try:

```
$('select[name="DBpick"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#inputField').val($(this).val());
    if (history.pushState) { // checks if supported
        window.history.pushState(null, "New Page Title", "?"+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

Or, you can simply change the HASH at the end of your URL. For example, to change:

```
mydomain.com/my-page.html#old
// to
mydomain.com/my-page.html#new
```

Use this:

```
$('select[name="DBpick"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#inputField').val($(this).val());
    window.location.hash = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, it actually works :-) Thank you so much. If I could bother you for one more question. Do you think I can update the url with the new input? Because the graphing calculator use values from the url to update the graph.

Comment: @AndiR.Milhomme, pleasure. Which part of the URL? Can you give me an example of the URL and the part you want to update?

Comment: Thank you ! I have figured it out. I simply had to simulate a keyup event. You have saved my life nonetheless. I appreciated that.

Comment: @AndiR.Milhomme - too late, I have just updated my answer. Take a look anyway, you may learn something :) That has to be worth an upvote? :) Good luck with the rest of it.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great notion I have learned. I'm sure it'll be useful someday.